# oracle: how to find the student met with prerequisite

Tags: oracle

I am a new in oracle. how to find the student met with prerequisite

```
SELECT
    c.course_no,
    c.description,
    c.prerequisite,
    level AS level_course,
    stu.student_id
FROM
    course c
    INNER JOIN section s ON c.course_no = s.course_no
    INNER JOIN enrollment e ON s.section_id = e.section_id
    INNER JOIN student stu ON e.student_id = stu.student_id
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR c.course_no = c.prerequisite
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNG0G.png **COURSE TABLE**

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asy8F.png **ENROLLMENT TABLE** https://i.stack.imgur.com/1axEi.png   **SECTION TABLE**[image][image]
[image]

Comment: I cannot answer this question   not enough information

Comment: what columns and result do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

You might need to add `START WITH` before `CONNECT BY`.

Here take course_no 20 for example.

You can remove  `AND c.course_no = 20` to see about all the courses.

Note: also adjusted the columns to make it more clear

```
SELECT
    level AS level_course,
    c.course_no,
    e.section_id,
    c.prerequisite,
    c.description,
    stu.student_id
FROM
    course c
    INNER JOIN section s ON c.course_no = s.course_no
    INNER JOIN enrollment e ON s.section_id = e.section_id
    INNER JOIN student stu ON e.student_id = stu.student_id
START WITH c.prerequisite IS NULL AND c.course_no = 20
CONNECT BY
    PRIOR c.course_no = c.prerequisite
```